# check if VT-x is activated without having to reboot in Linux?

Tags: linux, virtualization, virtualbox

I have a laptop with Intel Core i5 M 450 @ 2.40GHz which apparently has VT-x but not VT-d. I have Ubuntu 12.04 32bit but would like to have a virtual 64bit terminal-based Linux running on it. How do I know if the BIOS has this VT-x feature activated without having to reboot?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use *rdmsr* from *msr-tools* to read register *IA32_FEATURE_CONTROL* (address *0x3a*).  The kernel module *msr* has to be loaded for this.

On most Linux systems:

```
sudo modprobe msr
sudo rdmsr 0x3a
```

Values `3` and `5` mean it's activated.

Comment: `sudo rdmsr 0x3a` gives me `5`

Comment: As far as I understand 3 and 5 mean VT-x is activated.

Comment: Here's a bit more on those MSR bits: http://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Activating_the_Intel_VT_Virtualization_Feature http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/15555/can-a-hypervisor-rootkit-enable-hardware-assisted-virtualization-when-it-has-bee

Comment: I am getting value "7" with Linux kernel version 4.8.15, so the VMXON/VT-x option is set and is locked? Interesting.

Comment: On AMD Ryzen I get `rdmsr: CPU 0 cannot read MSR 0x0000003a`.

Comment: Installing msr-tools package on Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial Xerus) is as easy as running the following command on terminal:

`sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install msr-tools`

Comment: This fails on a `AMD RX-427BB` too: `rdmsr: CPU 0 cannot read MSR 0x0000003a`

Answer (score 21):

You can use

```
sudo kvm-ok
```

from [cpu-checker](https://launchpad.net/cpu-checker).  On Intel, which has the most complicated logic, kvm-ok [checks](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~cpu-checker-dev/cpu-checker/trunk/view/head:/kvm-ok#L78) that if bit 0 of `rdmsr 0x3a` (the lock bit) is set, bit 2 (which allows virt use outside of SMX mode, something to do with trusted boot) must also be set.  If the output of `rdmsr 0x3a` is anything but **1** or **3**, you will be able to use kvm.  kvm will set bit 2 of the msr if necessary, I expect virtualbox and the rest have the same logic.

Comment: Not available in Fedora repositories FC36

Answer (score 16):

Install cpu-checker and run "kvm-ok"

If the CPU is enabled, you should see something like:

```
INFO: /dev/kvm exists
KVM acceleration can be used
```

othewise

```
INFO: /dev/kvm does not exist
HINT:   sudo modprobe kvm_intel
INFO: Your CPU supports KVM extensions
INFO: KVM (vmx) is disabled by your BIOS
HINT: Enter your BIOS setup and enable Virtualization Technology (VT),
   and then hard poweroff/poweron your system
KVM acceleration can NOT be used
```

Comment: The `kvm-ok` is just for ubuntu systems. It can’t be used on debian or red hat.

Comment: On RHEL derivatives we have `virt-host-validate` which is provided by `libvirt-client`

Comment: on Ryzen Fedora 36 virt-host-validate says "Checking if device /dev/kvm exists                                   : FAIL (Check that the 'kvm-intel' or 'kvm-amd' modules are loaded & the BIOS has enabled virtualisation). Which doesn't completely clarify whether I need to re-boot to check the BIOS (although kvm-amd is not loaded according to lsmod)

Comment: @shgnlnc: 2023: available for debian and many other distros now!

Answer (score 7):

you can use:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cpu-checker
kvm-ok
```

Answer (score 6):

In linux you can check cpuinfo:

```bash
cat /proc/cpuinfo| egrep "vmx|svm"
```

Comment: This will only show if VT-x is supported by the CPU, not if it is activated in the BIOS.

Comment: Are you sure? When I'm inside my vm it give me an empty line but my cpu  supports amd-v? In cpu-z I can see amd-v even when I disabled secure virtual machine in the bios?

Comment: @Betterdev I'm not sure the virtual CPU is relevant. Anyway, by saying a CPU info tool reports the presence of AMD-V, despite it being unusable because you disabled SVM in the firmware, you're proving scai's point...

Comment: This only shows if the CPU has one of those particular extensions; it won't show anything relevant to the BIOS configuration. Check out the full output without `grep` to see what it's about.

Answer (score 5):

I found that scai's answer doesn't work on my AMD Ryzen systems.

This however works really well for me, even on Intel:

```bash
if systool -m kvm_amd -v &> /dev/null || systool -m kvm_intel -v &> /dev/null ; then
    echo "AMD-V / VT-X is enabled in the BIOS/UEFI."
else
    echo "AMD-V / VT-X is not enabled in the BIOS/UEFI"
fi
```

(`systool` is found in the `sysfsutils` package on most distros.)

For Intel's VT-D / AMD's IOMMU, I came up with this solution:

```bash
if compgen -G "/sys/kernel/iommu_groups/*/devices/*" > /dev/null; then
    echo "AMD's IOMMU / Intel's VT-D is enabled in the BIOS/UEFI."
else
    echo "AMD's IOMMU / Intel's VT-D is not enabled in the BIOS/UEFI"
fi
```

(It even worked for me if the iommu kernel parameters are not set.)

Comment: Note: This requires the `sysfsutils` package, but does not return an error if you don't have it (it just returns "you don't have virt stuff").

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach to confirm that Vt-D is enabled in the BIOS is through the Linux system. If the VT-D is enable in the BIOS and `Iommu=on` in the `grub.cfg` then the below folder structure is created automatically to hold the Virtual devices.

`/sys/kernel/iommu_groups/0/devices/0000:00:00.0`

Whereas if either one of the options VT-D or Iommu is not configured/enabled then the above mentioned folder structure is not created. This behavior is confirmed in CentOS 7.4 and Ubuntu.  Hopefully this behavior is similar for other operating systems as well but this would need to be confirmed.

Comment: On Ryzen and Fedora 36 I have /sys/kernel/iommu_groups/0/devices/0000:00:01.0/ (01 not 00). And can't run KVM and don't know if I have to reboot to check BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

Coming late to this party but it may be a long-lived question/answer. On Ryzen, Fedora 36, none of the other answers completely clarify whether I need to reboot. Red Hat provides [this](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/5/html/virtualization/sect-virtualization-tips_and_tricks-verifying_virtualization_extensions)

In short, to check AMD CPU:

```
$ grep -E 'svm|vmx' /proc/cpuinfo
```

(but I know that Ryzen is capable) Then,

```
# lsmod | grep kvm
```

To check for kvm_amd or kvm_intel. No `kvm_amd` module loaded, so that suggests a re-boot to check BIOS is needed. Will update later.

Comment: Yes, it was disabled in BIOS. Hard to find on Gigabyte A320M. Hidden under MIT / Advanced Frequency Settings!