# Android Studio Setup Wizard - Create Android virtual device

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, osx-elcapitan

I'm using Apple Mac OS X El Capitan and while trying to install [Android Studio 2.0](http://tools.android.com/download/studio/builds/2-0), I encounter following error:

> Unable to create a virtual device: Missing system image required for
>   an AVD setup

Unfortunately while `Android Studio Setup` tried to `Creating Android virtual device`, it failed and without ability to *retry*(

How do I complete failed step outside of that Android Studio Setup Wizard?

Comment: @codetoshare feel free to give it a whirl and then report back!

Answer (score 4):

once after installing of `android-studio` is finished, update your `sdk` through `sdk manager` to the latest available by selecting both the `android sdk tools` and `Extras` in check lisk.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure VT-x is enabled in your UEFI/BIOS.

On Linux, you can [check if it's enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116704/check-if-vt-x-is-activated-without-having-to-reboot-in-linux) by:

```
sudo modprobe msr
sudo rdmsr 0x3a
```

If it doesn't print `3` or `5`, VT-x is disabled, and emulation won't work. You will need to reboot and change the BIOS setting. The exact procedure depends on your hardware.

On OS X, you can check if the [CPU supports VT-x](http://kb.parallels.com/en/5653) using the following command:

```
sysctl -a | grep machdep.cpu.features
```

If the output contains `VMX` the CPU supports VT-x, but it could still be disabled. You might need an [EFI firmware update](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT203296). Disclaimer: I don't actually have a Mac to test.

Comment: as I mention in my question, I'm using `OS X`, so _NO_ BIOS, nor Linux applies here...

Comment: Sorry, this is what worked for me. For OS X, it seems VT-x [should be enabled by updates](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT203296). Maybe you have a different problem.